# How to raise viscosity of water

Tags: liquid, viscosity

I need to measure a machine for a liquid of which I know the viscosity (89 Kinetic Viscosity) but I don't have the liquid at hand. Is there a clever way of increasing viscosity of water to 89?

Comment: Add something to it. But what about something like honey at a suitable temperature?

Comment: @SolarMike actually I was just looking for a cheap and non wasteful solution. My liquid is Base Oil, I could buy some and test it, but now I have other concerns. My machine is a liquid filling machine. I am concerned if I use it with Base oil then base oil might solidify at nooks and crannys. I checked, the solidifying point is genereally 3-4 deg C less than pour point. The pour point of Base oil is -12 degrees C. I have never worked with base oil, can you tell whether I should be scared of solidification at regular tropical room temperature?

Comment: water with enough sugar dissolved in it to make it very viscous is basically honey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a whole class of chemicals called *thickening agents* used in the processed food industry which when dissolved in water, increase its viscosity. Some are used to thicken liquid foods so people who have difficulty swallowing can consume them; these are available in drug stores.

Comment: Yes, like corn starch. But how to know I have reached the required kinetic and dynamic viscosity?

Comment: with a viscometer.